# Check inside of ngStyle whether function returns a value

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I add a background image to my div like this:

```
[ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' + getPreviewImage(i, x) + ')'}">
```

How can I add a condition to this object? **I want to check whether `getPreviewImage(i,x)` returns an url, if not there shall be no image.**

```
getPreviewImage(slide, color) {
  return this.previewImages.find(file => file.slide === slide && file.color === color).url;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
[style.background-image]="getPreviewImage(i, x) ? 'url(' + getPreviewImage(i, x) + ')': false">
```